# Set filename using variable

Tags: export, files-and-directories

Is it possible to use variable filename to Export in mathematica?

For example, I want to export a number of files like
`Export["1.dat",data[[1]]]; Export["2.dat",data[[2]]]; Export["3.dat",data[[3]]]` and so on.

How do I set the filenames using a variable i such that I run do loop using variable i and  export files as 1.dat, 2.dat etc.

Comment: This was asked before. You can try `makeName[n_] := ToString[n] <> ".dat";
Do[Export[makeName[n], data[[n]]], {n, 1, 10}]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.